# Validate Values in the App.Config

Tags: c#, configuration, app-config

just a quick fire question and wondering on the correct approach.

In the appConfig in the Appsettings I want to validate the values that I have entered.So for example if I have

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="UseEncryption" value="false"/>
    <add key="MaxThreshold" value="10"/>
    <add key="ProcessDate" value="01/12/2012"/>
</appSettings>
```

the program compiles and executes as normal. However a support team can change these values and rerun the app. In light of coding a Gui to change all these values and validate them on the way in... is there another way to validate them.

For example I want to check that MaxThrehold is an Int, Processdate is a valid date etc

I was writing a function that would be run at the start of the application that would check each of the settings and stop the application if they where not correct.

Is this the best approach.. having a validator type function for each app setting.

I keep a class called CurrentEnvironment and in here I have all the get/sets for any settings I need in the App Config.. so for each Key I would also have a validitor function to check the values.

regards

Comment: You can also build `.xsd` schema describing what exactly you expect then using the command line `xsd` utility to generate a class. Then move the configuration to standalone XML file and try to serialize it as the above auto generated class. When something is wrong, you will get an exception you can handle. More work to do, but much more flexibility including option for complex types.

Comment: nice Soloution Shadow, but time isnt on my side :-)  I was using the Custom config and this is what got me thinking on the appSettings as a user could enter what they like in there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I was writing a function that would be run at the start of the application that would check each of the settings and stop the application if they where not correct.

That's a fine approach, though you do need to ensure that this function does run at the start of execution.

Another approach is to create a custom configuration section (inherit from [`ConfigurationSection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationsection.aspx) and add custom properties) - make sure these properties are of the types you want to test against. When the config file deserializes, if the types cannot be parsed properly, the application will not start up.

Comment: Hi Oded, yes believe it or not my application uses a custom config and it works well, which is why it got me wondering as to why there wasnt some sort of validation on the AppSettings

Comment: @Doiremik - With `appSettings` these are all just strings. That's how it was designed. It is not strongly typed otherwise.

Comment: Thanks Oded.. so I went with the approach and in my CurrentEnvironemt class I have a getter method for each Setting in the AppSettings and a validator. I then have a function that calls all the validators and builds up a string of error messages. If the string is empty all is good, otherwise an error is displayed and the program stops. What might be cool is to use reflection or something to find all the validator methods in the class and call them one by one.. but I havnt really got to far into reflection yet. Thanks again D

Answer (score 1):

for each of your keys use TryParse on the object

DateTime.TryParse(appsetting[keyname])

Comment: yes Marcus.. this is what my validator function and returns an error string there is a validation issue. I have one main method that calls all the validators and strings the error messages together